# openAL c++ Library to compare two Audio files

Tags: c++, audio, openal

I have to work on a small project. I am just preparing for it. It has to do with audio signals. I have heard that openAL a c++ library, focuses only on audio stuff. Can this library perform cross-correlation, fft etc to find if the two audio files are identical? If so, then please post any link to tutorials or any other helpful materials on openAL. And if not, then suggest me any other library that can perform these operations.

The idea is that I want an audio input, compare that input with other audio files, and want to get the best match, then print the corresponding word . Some thing like voice recognition, not the pure voice recognition but something similar.
Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

You dont need OpenAL for comparing files if they are exactly the same.
For a file comparison, look for the `<fstream>` header.

Comment: No!!!! i've edited my question, consider again

Comment: Oh man, why didnt you asked that in the beginning ? I am sure there are some libraries out there, I know someone who did this in Java, so just google man.

Comment: http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/about